# jQuery: Find every hidden row

Tags: jquery, html-table, hidden

This works but it also hides the top border for every cell inside every 2nd row. I only want it to hide the top border IF the first row of each table is hidden. Otherwise it shouldn't hide anything.

I have 4 tables on this page.

```
var validate = $("tr:nth-child(1)");

if (validate.is(":hidden")) {
    $("tr:nth-child(2) td").css("border-top-width", "0px");
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nBAgv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('table').each(function(){
    var validate = $("tr:nth-child(1)", this);

    if (validate.is(":hidden")) {
        $("tr:nth-child(2) td", this).css("border-top-width", "0px");
    }
})
```

Comment: @Smurfman82 is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bV7Hc/1/

Comment: This works in the fiddle but not on my page. I believe there may be another issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your penultimate line sets that attribute for ALL table rows matching the selector tr:nth-child(2) - which is the second row of every table.

Therefore, you need a more context-aware approach. I haven't tested the following (should work), but the concept is valid. You need to get the hidden 1st rows parent table, and then apply your .css("border-top-width","0px") to -only- that table's 2nd row.

```
$("tr:first-child").each(
     function(e) {
         if($(e).is(":hidden")) {
            $(e).parent().children("tr:nth-child(2)").css("border-top","0");
         }
     });
```

Comment: Still hides every row. :(

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand this correctly. Not sure. For the next row that appends every *hidden* row you want to remove the top border from each data cell in that row.

If that is the case, try doing it like this instead

```
$('table').each(function() {  
    $(this).find('tr').each(function() { 

        validate = $(this);

        if (validate.is(":hidden")) {
            $(validate).parent().find("tr:eq(1) td").css("border-top", "0px");
        } 
    });
});
```

For each table find the rows. Then for each row check if they're hidden. If they are find the next first row and remove it's border.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/SAV3V/).